# the conjugation of generated subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=A \times B$ be a group and $A_1 \leq A$, $B_1 \leq B$.
I want to know why all conjugates of $\langle A_1,B_1 \rangle$ in $G$, are of the form $\langle A_1^a,B_1^b \rangle$; $a \in A, b \in B$

Comment: I added the '"group-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Mr Lewis

Comment: How do you define $\langle A, B \rangle \le G?$

Comment: $\lbrace a^ib^j \mid a \in A , b \in B \rbrace$.

Comment: Really, it is the group generated by $A,B$.

Comment: Fine, that definition is fine, but then how does $\{a^ib^j\}$ relate to a subgroup of $A \times B$?  I mean, the elements of $A \times B$ are ordered pairs $(a, b)$ with $a \in A$, $b \in B$, but $a^ib^j$ is a product of an element of $A$ times an element of $B$, which only makes sense if they are in the same group.

Comment: Indeed, if $G=A \times B$, the we have three conditions. 1)$G=AB$ 2)$A \cap B=1$ 3)$A,B $ are normal in $G$. Now $a^ib^j \in AB=G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find it useful to note that $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle=A_1B_1$ is naturally isomorphic to $A_1\times B_1$.

Certainly all groups of the form $\langle A_1^a,B_1^b\rangle$ are conjugate to $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle$, as $\langle A_1^a,B_1^b\rangle=\langle A_1,B_1\rangle^{(a,b)}$.

Conversely if $H$ is conjugate to $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle$ then $H=\langle A_1,B_1\rangle^g$ for some $g\in A\times B$. We can write $g=(a,b)$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ so $H=\langle A_1,B_1\rangle^g=\langle A_1,B_1\rangle^{(a,b)}$.

Comment: Why $\langle A_1,B_1 \rangle \cong A_1 \times B_1$?

Comment: Elements of $A$ commute with elements of $B$ so $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle=A_1B_1$. Also $A_1\cap B_1\le A\cap B=\{1\}$ so $A_1\cap B_1=1$. This means $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle$ is the internal direct product of $A_1$ and $B_1$, so is isomorphic to $A_1\times B_1$.

Comment: Why $A_1 $ and $B_1$ are normal in $A_1B_1$?

Comment: If $g\in A_1B_1$ then $g=ab$ for some $a\in A_1$, $b\in B_1$. Since $a\in A_1$ and elements of $A$ commute with elements of $B$ you have $A_1^g=A_1^{ab}=A_1^b=A_1$, hence $A_1$ is normal in $A_1B_1$. A similar argument works for $B_1$.

Comment: No. $A_1 ^ b \in A$. It is not true

Comment: $A_1$ is a subgroup of $A$, elements of $B$ and therefore $B_1$ commute with elements of $A$ and therefore $A_1$, therefore for $b\in B_1$ we have $A_1^b=\{a^b|a\in A_1\}=\{a|a\in A_1\}=A_1$.

Comment: you said $A_1^{ab}=A_1^b$, but $A_1$ is not normal in $A$, why $A_1^{ab}=A_1^b$?

Comment: Because $a\in A_1$ and $A_1$ is normal in $A_1$

Comment: that is you say that every subgroup of $G$ has the form $A_1 \times B_1$? But it is true if $(|A|,|B|)=1$!!

Comment: your mistake is here i.e. $\langle A_1,B_1 \rangle=A_1B_1$ if $A_1B_1$ is a subgroup of $G$, but we dont know $A_1B_1 \le G$.

Comment: So we cant say $\langle A_1,B_1 \rangle=A_1B_1$ in generally

Comment: It's not generally true that every subgroup is of the form $A_1\times B_1$ where $A_1$ is taken as a subgroup of $A$ and $B_1$ as a subgroup of $B$ (for example if $A\cong B$ then $H=\{(a,a)|a\in A\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ but $H\cap A=H\cap B=\{1\}$) but it is true if $(|A|,|B|)=1$. If you take $A_1$ as a subgroup of $A$ and $B_1$ as a subgroup of $B$ then it's very easy to show $A_1B_1\le G$. Let $a_1,a_2\in A_1$ and $b_1,b_2\in B_1$ then $a_1b_1a_2b_2=a_1a_2b_1b_2\in A_1B_1$

Comment: your answer is not true because we cant say $\langle A_1,B_1 \rangle=A_1B_1$

Comment: $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $A_1$ and $B_1$, any such subgroup contains $A_1B_1$ and $A_1B_1$ is a subgroup, so $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle=A_1B_1$

Comment: $(a_1b_1)^{-1}=b_1^{-1}a_1^{-1}=a_1^{-1}b_1^{-1}$. The second equality is because elements of $A$ and elements of $B$ commute

Comment: yes i am confusing now

Comment: Thank you, you responsed to my questions(more and more), thank you so much

Comment: No problem, if you're still unsure then try to read / work slowly through my answer again, if you have any questions not fully answered in the comments feel free to ask for clarification

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are very patient, congratulation :)